# Python3 Subprocess File closing

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.6

I am learning python3 and I have some basic code for python3.6.6 from their website

But I am also running python on warning mode -Wd so it will tell me if there are any other errors even in a working program.

I am trying to do some basic shell scripting.

https://codecalamity.com/run-subprocess-run/

let's say I run

```
import subprocess
import os
print("Welcome to the obs program")

cmd=str(input("enter commands\n"))

print(cmd)

cmd=subprocess.run(cmd,
shell=True,
stdout=open(cmd+" stdout", 'w'),
stderr=open(cmd+" stderr",'w'),
bufsize=1
)
```

I get the error that I am not closing the file =(

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='ls -l stderr' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
  bufsize=1
```

so I tried

```
cmd.stdout.close()
cmd.stderr.close()
```

and it's still not closing the file =(

this doesn't mess my program up, I just want to make sure that I am closing my files.

Thanks!

Sorry I am new to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case, don't pass the result of `open` to a procedure that is not going to close it as you'll lose the handle, it's bad practice. You cannot be sure of the moment when python garbages collect and closes the file.

Your attempt doesn't work, you're trying to close other objects (`cmd.stdout` is handy when redirecting with `subprocess.PIPE` or `subprocess.STDOUT`).

Just use a context manager and handle *variables*:

```
with open(cmd+" stdout", 'wb') as fout, open(cmd+" stderr",'wb') as ferr:
    cmd=subprocess.run(cmd,
    shell=True,
    stdout=fout,
    stderr=ferr,
    bufsize=1
    )
```

when exiting the `with` block, the redirected output/error files are closed (no need to call `close` on them)

Comment: yes you're right I didn't put the correct code, I accidently put what I was thinking should work. I like your implementation and I'll take a look at it. Python3 seems to have some issues with this stuff, so I might just write it in perl, but thank you very much this seems interesting

Comment: too lazy to check but `wb` mode is probably required for python 3.